# How to correct POST request that returns status 404 in client code?

Tags: http-headers, http-status-code-404

I am making a POST request to login but the status of the response is 404. The request is made from localhost to an external server. What headers may be missing in the POST request?

I have tried with different headers (of the type `access-control-allow` - ***, `Content-Length`, `X-Content-Type-Options`, `Accept`, `Accept-encoding`) and the answer is always 404.

```
    httpOptions={
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    }

    login( user:object){
        return this.http.post(this.env.api+'auth/user/authenticate', user, httpOptions);
    }

**user={"email":"xxx@xxx.xx","password":"yyyy"}
```

I hope that the service has a successful status as well as that it returns a coded token with the user's id. Currently the status is `404` and without token

Comment: What is the value of `this.env.api`? Maybe there is a slash missing at its end?

Comment: It is a url, and verify it and that same variable use to make another post request that returns a status 200

Comment: The code 404 says that the URL is wrong. Maybe `auth/user/authenticate` is not correct? It would be very unusual for a server to use 404 to signal failed logon or unsupported formats. But without knowing the concrete API, how should anyone be able to help here?

Comment: I do not have access to API, only the endpoints, type of request and information to send me. They indicate that I need a header but I do not know how to determine the missing header.
 Is there any way to know?

Comment: Read the documentation or ask for more documentation 